# javascript string replace method

Tags: javascript, html, json, dom

I have a problem with the JavaScript string replace method, i tried a lot, still don't have a clue what is wrong. Please give me some advice. Thanks.

Basically, I have a question string and an array answer, I want to replace the answer in the Question string with "**__**".

I have the following JavaScript array:

But when I try to replace the string, something funny happens:

```js
var quiz = [{
    "Question": " ",
    "Answer_choic": [],
    "Answer": [],
    "Points": 0,
    "totalPoints": 0
}];

quiz[0].Question = String(document.getElementById('QuestionName').value)

//first
    var QuestionArray= new Array();
    function selectAnswers() {
        var QuestionValue = document.getElementById("QuestionName").value;
        //alert(QuestionValue);

        quiz[0].Question=String(document.getElementById('QuestionName').value)
        quiz[0].Points=parseInt(document.getElementById('Points').value);
        quiz[0].totalPoints+=parseInt(document.getElementById('Points').value);

        QuestionArray= QuestionValue.split(' ');
        for(var i=0; i<QuestionArray.length; i++) {
            QuestionArray[i] ='<span class="answerWord" id="Answer'+i+'" onclick="toggleAnswer('+i+');setAnswer(QuestionArray['+i+']) "> '+QuestionArray[i] +'</span>';

        }


//then trigger this function
function setAnswer(s) {
    //s is typeof string, i double check it
    quiz[0].Answer.push(s);

    // example of quiz[0].Question: "abc bbb aaa dddd"
    // example of s will be any substring of above like: "bbb"
    if (QuestionType.value == 'FillInLine') {

        // this doesnt work
        quiz[0].Question = quiz[0].Question.replace(s, '______');

        //but if i change s to, let say a string "ab", and the question contain the substring "ab", it works fine. im really sure variable "s" is typeof string. Can anybody tell me why?   
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it correct that `quiz[0].Question` is `" "`? Do you know about the `.indexOf` function?

Comment: no. it contain the element i need to replace for sure, cuz i have try just to enter the content of s instead of variable s

Comment: i played a bit, it seems your code is fine. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Zw3M/1023/)

Comment: It seems like you've ruled out this code as the problem.  Can you show a call to setAnswer that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Are you executing this line `quiz[0].Question = String(document.getElementById('QuestionName').value)` before the page has loaded, and this element's value is available?

Comment: Works well [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CdGwD/) can you provide a fiddle with the actual values you're having problems with? **Edit:** I think @AndyG may be on the right path to finding the problem

Comment: works well for me also

Comment: As Andy mentioned Try moving `quiz[0].Question = String(document.getElementById('QuestionName').value)` to somewhere within function and it worked fine for me.

Comment: the quiz[0].Question contain the right element, it just cannot replace the string after the method

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any issue with your code.  http://jsfiddle.net/VBgx4/3/

So s is a string that is getting passed into your function.  If the `Question` contains the substring equal to `s` then it will replace that matching section of `Question`.  If `s` is not in `Question` then `Question` will remain unchanged.

Comment: that's what i think too, is it because i have another event trigger this event?